# Could I run two functions inside OnTriggerEnter?

Tags: unity

My weapon fire a gameobject "clone bullet" with a script attached on it.
There is a part from the script doesn't work. That part is when this "clone bullet" hit object with "enemy" tag, check if this bullet named "rpg)_bullet(Clone)".

```
    public GameObject Blood_prefab,dust_prefab;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider bulletv)
{

    if (bulletv.gameObject.CompareTag("enemy"))
    {

        if (gameObject.transform.name == "rpg)_bullet(Clone)")
        {
            // this part doesn't work
            gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
            Instantiate(Blood_prefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);

            foreach (Transform ty in transform)
            {
                if (ty.transform.name == "Heavygun_bullet")
                {
                    Destroy(ty);
                }

                if (ty.transform.name == "Particle_System")
                {
                    ty.transform.position = gameObject.transform.position;
                }

            }


        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            Instantiate(Blood_prefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        }

    }

}
```

## Update 1

In case someone looking for a solution for this. I solve it by using One empty object with two childs objects (particleSystem for smoke and bullet shape object). And attach this script on Empty object.

```
    public GameObject Blood_prefab,dust_prefab;
public Transform bullet_shape;
public bool Smoke_Bullet = false;

public void Start()
{
    if (Smoke_Bullet == true)
    {
        foreach (Transform Bullet in gameObject.transform)
        {
            if (Bullet.name == "Heavygun_bullet")
            {
                 bullet_shape = Bullet;
            }
        }
    }
} // End start................

public void Update()
{
    if (Smoke_Bullet == true)
    {
        if ( bullet_shape.gameObject.activeSelf == false)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject, 1); // destroy after 1 second
        }
    }
} // end Update..............

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider bulletv)
{

    if (Smoke_Bullet == false)
    {
        if (bulletv.gameObject.CompareTag("enemy"))
        {

            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            Instantiate(Blood_prefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);

        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (bulletv.gameObject.CompareTag("enemy"))
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>().isTrigger = false; // use Capsule to fit bullet shape and sphere have bigger radius. For my bullet, Capsule [Radius 3.3,Height 10] Sphere [Raidus 10]. Both triggers are true.
            bullet_shape.gameObject.SetActive(false); // to have time for smoke
            gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true; // to stop bullet movement 
            Instantiate(Blood_prefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the bullet checking its own name?

Comment: Because I'm using the same script for all kind of bullets. Because this weapon is "Grenade launcher", It should have rigidbody with gravity is true. It's working except that when hit enemy body. The somkeTrail is hide and give unrealistic image.

Comment: Sounds like you want a grenade script that does grenade stuff, and a bullet script that does bullet stuff. That will be more robust than distinguishing by name.

Comment: Enemy and player using one script for their bullets is more simple and easy. Yes , I need to distinguish between bullets to add more features. Not make all of them look the same !!

Answer (score 0):

Please read Update 1.
script...

```
    public GameObject Blood_prefab,dust_prefab;
    public Transform bullet_shape;
    public bool Smoke_Bullet = false;

    public void Start()
{
if (Smoke_Bullet == true)
{
    foreach (Transform Bullet in gameObject.transform)
    {
        if (Bullet.name == "Heavygun_bullet")
        {
             bullet_shape = Bullet;
        }
    }
}
} // End start................

public void Update()
{
if (Smoke_Bullet == true)
{
    if ( bullet_shape.gameObject.activeSelf == false)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject, 1); // destroy after 1 second
    }
}
} // end Update..............

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider bulletv)
{

if (Smoke_Bullet == false)
{
    if (bulletv.gameObject.CompareTag("enemy"))
    {

        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        Instantiate(Blood_prefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);

    }
}
else
{
    if (bulletv.gameObject.CompareTag("enemy"))
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>().isTrigger = false; // use Capsule to fit bullet shape and sphere have bigger radius. For my bullet, Capsule [Radius 3.3,Height 10] Sphere [Raidus 10]. Both triggers are true.
        bullet_shape.gameObject.SetActive(false); // to have time for smoke
        gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true; // to stop bullet movement 
        Instantiate(Blood_prefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);

    }
}
}
```